# Indexing full-text and descriptive metadata in Solr

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I have a small set of descriptive metadata (~50) and for each of them a corresponding full text file (.txt). My understanding is that the Apache Tika framework is used for detecting and extracting metadata and structured text from various types of documents. However, I would also need to implement a linkage mechanism whereby a given metadata is matched to its full-text. Can this be done in Solr?

Thanks,

Ilaria

Comment: Solr can index text files easily, but I think I missing the point. Could you explain in details your setup. How metadata is linked to those text files

Comment: I guess what you want is, given some metadata, fetch the relevant document?

Comment: @Srikanth, it is exactly what I want. I just wonder how feasible and complicated this is. Generally speaking, the full-text filename (numerical) matches to one of the metadata tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have metadata and the document content, you can index the metadata and store the content. Your field definition would look something like this

```
<field name="filename" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
... <!-- other metadata /-->
<field name="content" type="text" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
```

This will allow you to search by any metadata, and give you back the content. You can add as much meta information as required to search the text. I wouldn't index the full text as there is already some structured metadata available.

Apache TIKA extracts meta information from HTML pages etc. Since you already have the metadata available, you need not use TIKA. Besides, AFAIK, Tika does not work with plain text files.

**Edit 1**:

Ok, so the link between the metadata and content will be maintained in Solr. For ex, if you have

```
File1.txt <-> Metadata1.txt
```

You could have one record (document) in Solr that has (no. of metadatafields + 1 plaintextcontent field). This gives you the flexibility to look up the document by any metadata. For example,

```
q=filename:File1.txt
```

or

```
q=filesize:[1 to 100]
```

where `filename` and `filesize` are example metadata fields. `plaintextcontent` would be your text file content, so thus in your Solr schema, you have your link.

Now the trick is to setup the indexing. Here's one way to do it -

Indexing the text file is very simple. You could use the [DataImportHandler's PlainTextEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#PlainTextEntityProcessor).

Indexing the metadata along with it could be slightly tricky (need to understand the structure of metadata). You could use [LineEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#LineEntityProcessor) or  any one of the [Transformers of DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Transformer), depending on what suits you best.

Comment: Srikanth, thanks for this, much appreciated. I am still trying to get my head around this. What I really want to understand is how feasible is to make the link between the metadata (coming from file X) and the full-text (coming from file Y). Do you hardcode the link between the metadata and the full-text? (e.g. occuring on a specific tag) I will end up with thousand of full-text and metadata and I would like to know how Solr can work with my requirements. Thanks indeed, I.

Comment: @ilariac - have added some more details, hope that explains things better?

Comment: thanks again for the extra info. It starts making all much more sense, but still confused about how to do make the linkage. When you say that "link between the metadata and content will be maintained in Solr", where do you see that linkage taking place? My metadata are MARC 21 and virtually any tag there can be used as long as matches to the full-text filename (inside the full-text there is nothing more than plain text). My initial understanding is that I might be able using Transformers of DataImportHandler, is that correct?

Comment: @ilariac - Think of every document in Solr as a row in a table. Such table will contain many columns, one each for the meta data (could be multi-valued in case of multiple tags) and one Blob column that contains the text. Thus each row (or Document here) is now a relation. Makes sense?

Comment: It actually does, thank you so much! It all makes much more sense now.